# Producing all possible combinations from a table ignoring blanks in R

Tags: r

I have exported a table, with headers, from excel to an R table. However, each column has a different lenght in the table, for example:

[image]

I use the following to store the table in an R object:

```
table1 <- read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", fill= TRUE, header=TRUE)
```

Then to get the combinations I use:

```
comboTable <- expand.grid(table1$Laptop, table1$Hard_Disk, table1$RAM)
```

The issue with the procedure above is that I am getting all the possible combinations, incluiding the possible ones with the blank cells I imported from excel.

Is there a way to obtain the combination ignoring those cells in blank? also is there an option to `expand.grid()` to get all combinations from the table without calling each single column?

Comment: comboTable <- Expand.gird(table1) returns all possible combinations without the need of calling columns independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have this dataframe when reading your file.

```
mydf <- data.frame(Laptop = c("Doll", "Landovo", "Ocer", "Toshibo", "UFO"), 
                   Hard_Disk = c(100,500,1000,NA, NA), RAM = c(32,64,NA,NA, NA))
```

A simple solution would consist in selecting non-na indexes for each of your variable, like this.

```
expand.grid(Laptop = mydf$Laptop[!is.na(mydf$Laptop)], 
            Hard_Disk = mydf$Hard_Disk[!is.na(mydf$Hard_Disk)], 
            RAM = mydf$RAM[!is.na(mydf$RAM)])
```

**EDIT**
Using @LAP answer and to generalize over all columns in a simple command, you can use this instruction.

```
expand.grid(apply(mydf, 2, na.omit))
```

Comment: You can just use `expand.grid(df$Laptop, na.omit(df$Hard_Disk), na.omit(df$RAM))`.

Comment: This works. However, I would like to know if there is a way of selecting the non-na indexes without the need of modifying each column at a time. For example if I had 30 columns I would need to do the same instruction 30 times: column1 = mfdf$column1[!is.na(mydf$column1)]]. Is there a way to give the dataframe an irregular shape so that expand.grid() works without that instruction. This also in case I had to modify the orginal table by having to add and/or delete columns.

Comment: @Ricardo I have adjusted my answer to meet up with your constraints, also using LAP's remark.

Comment: That `apply` solution is nice!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @AshOfFire's answer, if you have empty strings instead of `NA`:

```
df <- data.frame(Laptop = c("Doll", "Landovo", "Ocer", "Toshibo", "UFO"),
                 Hard_Disk = c("100","500","1000", "", ""),
                 RAM = c("32","64","","",""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

use `lapply` to convert them to `NA`:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x){
  ifelse(x == "", NA, x)
})
```

and then use `expand.grid` with `na.omit` on the relevant variables:

```
expand.grid(df$Laptop, na.omit(df$Hard_Disk), na.omit(df$RAM), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      Var1 Var2 Var3
1     Doll  100   32
2  Landovo  100   32
3     Ocer  100   32
4  Toshibo  100   32
5      UFO  100   32
6     Doll  500   32
7  Landovo  500   32
8     Ocer  500   32
9  Toshibo  500   32
10     UFO  500   32
11    Doll 1000   32
12 Landovo 1000   32
13    Ocer 1000   32
14 Toshibo 1000   32
15     UFO 1000   32
16    Doll  100   64
17 Landovo  100   64
18    Ocer  100   64
19 Toshibo  100   64
20     UFO  100   64
21    Doll  500   64
22 Landovo  500   64
23    Ocer  500   64
24 Toshibo  500   64
25     UFO  500   64
26    Doll 1000   64
27 Landovo 1000   64
28    Ocer 1000   64
29 Toshibo 1000   64
30     UFO 1000   64
```